# Will direct debit end automatically when loan is paid

Tags: united-states, ach, direct-debit

If a loan is paid automatically each month through direct debit, will the direct debit stop when the loan reaches zero or will money continue to be withdrawn until the person paying the loan stops the direct debit?

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer, but you should really wait at least a day in case someone else answers it better.

Comment: I've never seen "them" keep on withdrawing after the payments are supposed to end, but as Rupert stated, it all depends on the honesty *and competency* of the other party.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The direct debit is an authority to withdraw money from your account. Depending on how it was set up it may limit how much may be withdrawn, how often and for how long. I haven't seen a direct debit agreement that limits the total that may be withdrawn, but they may exist.

A reputable creditor will stop taking your money when they're supposed to, which would be when the loan is paid off.

Answer (score 2):

it's so much easier to stop payments then have to go asking for your money after a bank has taken it.

I have had monthly homeowners payments taken after I sold a property. Took a lot of effort to get my money back. Wish I had taken a few minutes to stop the payments earlier.

Comment: That does sound like a good idea to be sure.